# Shadowsocks Proxy error: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, proxy, socks

I am using a Shadowsocks server on my EC2 instance, and my client is a physical device (thinclient). Both use Amazon Linux 2.

When I test the authentication between my client and my server, I get this error:

> [Thinclient]# curl --socks5 localhost:1080 ifconfig.io
>
> ======>curl: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.
>
> [server]#less /var/log/messages
>
> ======>getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected

Both configuration files on the client and the server are fine!

Has anyone had the same issue with Shadowsocks? Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Well, lets start with the basics - are you SURE that Shadowsocks is running on `localhost` on port 1080, and not some other app? Also, note that `--socks5` and `--socks5-hostname` have been obsolete since curl 7.21.7, use `--proxy`/`-x` with a `socks5://` or `socks5h://` url instead. Also, do you expect curl or the proxy to resolve the IP of the `ifconfig.io` hostname? It may make a difference when establishing the connection between the proxy and the target host, depending on your network topology.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when i used ss-redir as client. To get local socks5 proxy you need to use ss-local:

```
systemctl start shadowsocks-libev-local@your-config-name
```